# Find the values of $x$ for which $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{1+n^2x^2}$, $x>0$, $a\geq 0$, converges uniformly in given interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Find the values of x for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{1+n^2x^2}, x>0, a\geq 0$ converges uniformly on (1)$[0,1]$ and (2)$[0, \infty)$

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^{a}}{1+n^2x^2} \\ f'(x) = \frac{ax^{a-1}(1+n^2x^2)-x^a2n^2x}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} = 0 \\x=c=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt (2-a)}\frac{1}{n} \\f(c) = \left(\frac{a}{2-a}\right)^{\frac{a}{2}}\frac{1}{n^a}\frac{2-a}{a}$

Series is convergent for all $a \geq 1$ and divergent for $a<1$

Now how to see uniform convergence in given intervals. a is also coming into picture

Comment: Since $x^{a}$ comes out of the summation pointwise  convergence does not depend on $a$.

Comment: But if a<1, we can not apply weistrass. It means series nature we can not determine for 0<a<1

Comment: You have stated that the series is divergent for $a<1$. This is false. The series converges for all $a\geq 0$ and all $x >0$.

Comment: As per weirstrass, if $\sum f(x ) \leq \sum M_n$, and $\sum M_n$ is convergent (here convergent for $a \geq 1)$ we can say it is uniformly convergent for a >=1. But for 0<a<1, we can not say any thing. In both cases, a >=0

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should say the series converges *uniformly* when $a > 1$ [$a = 1$ there is no dominant series, since the maximal value form a harmonic series which is divergent]. I’m assuming you are requested to find values of $a$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @xbh This is a previous year Question of an exam. Generally it may not be wrong. But pls feel free to correct if any thing wrong

Comment: Look up partial fraction expansion of coth (or cot); then use the nearest singularity to determine the answer.

Comment: @skbmoore can u pls elaborate? i could not find any connectivity between cot $\pix$ and this series form(https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Partial_Fractions_Expansion_of_Cotangent)

Comment: @skbmoore If i put x = 1/y, then $\pi \cot (\frac{\pi}{y}) = 1/2 + (2/y) \sum \frac{y^2}{1-n^2y^2}$ ..... Now how do i proceed?